# Strange NPE deep inside MediaSessionCompat

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification.mediastyle

I have seen similar questions posted about `MediaSessionCompat` but they are all pretty old, in fact most predate AndroidX and they point at it being fixed in newer versions.

This crash is happening with `androidx.media:media:1.2.1` on various phones from Android 8 through 11. It is always `MediaSessionImplApi21`. Works fine for me on every phone I've tried.

This issue is new for me as of my latest release. The two big changes I made are that I added a progress bar to my `MediaStyle` notification and that I upgraded to `1.2.1` from `1.0.0`.

This is the exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Callback android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplApi21.getCallback()' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Callback$MediaSessionCallbackApi21.getSessionImplIfCallbackIsSet(MediaSessionCompat.java:1907)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Callback$MediaSessionCallbackApi21.onMediaButtonEvent(MediaSessionCompat.java:1597)
       at android.media.session.MediaSession$CallbackMessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaSession.java:1471)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

If my `Callback` wasn't set them a lot of things wouldn't work.

Also my code looks like this:

```
MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(context, TAG);
mediaSessionCompat.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback);
```

So there's really no room to not set the `Callback`.

Any idea what it could be?

From looking at the code and where it crashed:

```
        private MediaSessionImplApi21 getSessionImplIfCallbackIsSet() {
            MediaSessionImplApi21 sessionImpl;
            synchronized (mLock) {
                sessionImpl = (MediaSessionImplApi21) mSessionImpl.get();
            }
            return MediaSessionCompat.Callback.this == sessionImpl.getCallback()
                    ? sessionImpl : null;
        }
```

It is crashing on `sessionImpl.getCallback()`. Which probably means it either got recycled because `mSessionImpl` is a `WeakReference` or it was set to null to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug and has now been patched and will hopefully be out on `1.2.2` https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178694750